# Cannot start or move a VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am fairly new to Google Cloud platform and cloud computing as a whole. I had a**f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)** type of instance running. GCP gave me a warning that the instance was overutilized and I should change it to **g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)** type of instance. When I went to upgrade, it began to restart my instance but gave me the error

`Starting VM instance '<instance name>' failed. Error: The zone 'projects/<project id>/zones/asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.`

I have waited for some time (more than 12 hours) to start it again and getting the same error. I edited the instance manually and changed it to **g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)** but still getting the same error.

I tried moving the instance to a different zone in same region using *move instances* in google cloud SDK Shell, but got an error and found out that instances in terminated state cannot be moved.

I just need to get my instance up and running, so please help here.

Answer (score 1):

Did some further investigation. Indeed the resource shortage is still ongoing in the region. However changing the machine type to E2-micro/small then starting the instance should work for you.

Comment: Tried it. Changed it to E2 micro and tried starting - didn't work, then changed it to E2 small - didn't work. If there is resource shortage in region, at least  there should be a simpler way to move the instance to a new zone/region.

Comment: You can easily move to a new zone/region if you have an existing snapshot of the instance's disk you want to start. If you do not have a snapshot you cannot create now since the instance has to be running to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an existing snapshot of the VM as it is on a week old. I was still in process of setting it up completely. Nevertheless I had done considerable work and would hate to repeat everything.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I am still facing it. What I ended up doing is I switched to `asia-south1-c`.

Comment: how did you switch the zone? I cannot switch zone using moveInstance API while the instance is in terminated status.

Comment: by starting a new vm from a pre existing snapshot. As Erhard Czving pointed out, you cannot create a snapshot of a vm which is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to create a snapshot of a terminated instance from the web console and then create a new VM using that snapshot in a different region. Then deleted the old VM and snapshot.